# Do the unseq execution policy require the iterators' value_type to be Cpp17CopyAssignable?

Tags: c++, c++17, stl-algorithm

The following snipped does not compile with GCC 10 ([Compiler Explorer link](https://godbolt.org/z/s5rW18)):

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <execution>

struct T
{
  int const ID; // Not Cpp17CopyAssignable
};

int f(std::vector<T> const &v)
{
  if (v.empty()) return -1;
  
  return std::min_element(std::execution::par_unseq, v.begin(), v.end(),
                          [](T const &lhs, T const &rhs) { return lhs.ID < rhs.ID; })->ID;
}
```

because `T` is not *`Cpp17CopyAssignable`*:

```
 error: use of deleted function 'T& T::operator=(const T&)'
  643 |                 __min_val = __obj.__min_val;
      |                 ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I cannot find such requirement in either cppreference or [[algorithms]](http://eel.is/c++draft/#algorithms). Did I miss it?

Comment: Looks like a bug in `g++`. `clang++` doesn't have a problem with this and I can't see why it should.

Comment: You get a slightly different error if you make the default constructor explicitly `delete`d that makes the reason a little clearer: https://godbolt.org/z/Kr4bEK

Comment: @TedLyngmo It's strange that Clang accepts it even with `-stdlib=libstdc++`...

Comment: Isn't you reasoning wrong? The error message indicates that the problem is not that `T` is not _default-constructible_, but that it is not _assignable_.

Comment: @DanielLangr That's an excellent point :-)

Comment: @DanielLangr Very true. I'll edit the question. I still don't find any requirement that `*first` must be `Cpp17CopyAssignable` for `std::min_element`

Comment: @PilarLatiesa AFAIK, libstdc++ does not have it's own implementation of parallel algorithms (yet). It uses Intel TBB as a backend, at least with GCC. It is possible that when used with Clang, it falled back to serial backend in your setup (see, e.g., [parallel_backend.h](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/pstl/parallel_backend.h))

Comment: The error seems to be triggered here: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/pstl/unseq_backend_simd.h#L643 The problem is with that `_ValueType __min_val;` member variable. In theory, the algorithm shouldn't require a copy of a value type here, but libstdc++ seems to do so :| I would agree that this is a bug, unless there is some corresponding requirement in the standard (which I also cannot find).

Comment: @DanielLangr It points to a libstdc++ header. I've added a compiler explorer link to reproduce.

Comment: @DanielLangr If nobody posts an answer I'll file a PR in a couple of days.

Comment: @DanielLangr Filed [PR99522](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=99522)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C++ standard doesn't require values of the sequence passed to a parallel algorithm to be assignable (nor copy-constructible, nor default-constructible) unless required by the non-parallel counterpart. An implementation that doesn't accept such values is non-conforming.

> **[algorithms.parallel.defns]/2** Parallel algorithms access objects indirectly accessible via their arguments by invoking the following functions:
> ...
> (2.2) — Operations on those sequence elements that are required by its specification.
> ...

This says the algorithm shouldn't demand more than is necessary from the value type.

Parallel algorithms are allowed to make copies of elements sometimes:

> **[algorithms.parallel.exec]/2** Unless otherwise stated, implementations may make arbitrary copies of elements (with type `T`) from sequences where `is_trivially_copy_constructible_v<T>` and `is_trivially_destructible_v<T>` are true.

But only for those elements that are trivially copy constructible, and then by copy constructor, not by assignment.